# Prepared Statement connection error : No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

```
<?php
echo "Lets run the program";
$id = 1;
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("Select Genre_Name from Practice.genre_list where Genre_ID = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param(i,$id );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result(s, $result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $result;
    echo "in if function";
}
else{
    echo "some issue";
}
?>

output:
```

> Lets run the program
>   Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/practice/preparedStatement.php on line 5
>       Connect failed: No such file or directory

After searching on web, I checked the configuration in php.ini file and mysql.sock is set properly, no issues with that.
Still not able to figure out why prepared statement is not working, I am able to connect using traditional approach of mysqli_connect(), but not with the OOA approach.

Comment: `new mysqli()` has 4 parameters, the fourth being the name of your database

Comment: Is the code you posted here preparedStatement.php? How do you call it?

Comment: I used command line to check for the working of code, even if the database is mentioned, it throws the same error.

Comment: What is line 5?

Comment: Line 5 correspond to connect statement, there was 1 more echo statement above which I removed.. The line 5 is shown below

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root');

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running on Linux. The setting in your PHP.ini file for mysql.default_socket is not pointing to the mysql socket.

Open a command line and type:

```
locate mysql.sock
```

After that, edit your PHP.ini and set:

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

Substitute the location of mysql.sock in place of /path/to/mysql.sock

It's fairly likely that the file is in /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, but it may vary depending on your server.

Comment: ; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

This is already set in php.ini file